# How can I get more shelves?

Tags: android, bonbon-cakery

I'm having trouble being able to stock more types of cakes. Since they go out of season, and I only have a limited number of shelves, I have to throw out stock to replace it with more popular goods.

I've bought the extra shelf from Pumpkin Products, but he only had one. I have space for more, but I don't have any more! Where can I get more shelves?

Answer (score 1):

To get more shelves: if you are allowed to place more you simply click an empty slot where you want a shelf and choose which of your available shelves you want to place. Shelf S, Shelf M, Shelf L and so on.

You get new types of shelves from gifts by various people.

Comment: Sorry didn't realize how old this was but I'm currently looking for answers too.

Comment: Hi Sukotto this is an answer space - if you have a new question, click the 'Ask Question' button on the top of the page. Link back to this question if it helps to provide context. I have removed your questions from this answer.